# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'softwareTabCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

As I believe the problem is at the beginning of the file, I've attached the following code:

```
    'use strict';

    /**
     * @ngdoc function
     * @name bitbloqApp.controller:softwareTabCtrl
     * @description
     * # softwareTabCtrl
     * Controller of the bitbloqApp
     */
    angular.module('bitbloqApp')
        .controller('softwareTabCtrl',softwareTabCtrl);

    function softwareTabCtrl( $rootScope, $scope, $timeout, $translate, $window, bloqsUtils, bloqs, bloqsApi,
            $log, $document, _, ngDialog, $location, userApi, alertsService, web2board, robotFirmwareApi, web2boardOnline, projectService,
            utils) {
//code
};
```

Full code:

https://gist.github.com/raulvillora/e6ef8fdda865230b3d9a71206c20702a

Comment: you need to inject your dependancies if you use `'use strict'`, try adding: `softwareTabCtrl.$inject = ["$rootScope", "$scope", ... , "projectService","utils"];`

Comment: I have the same problem using softwareTabCtrl.$inject

Comment: show your html where you insert your scripts (also see if the error occurs when you remove `use strict`)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/raulvillora/79992580e587f3d1cc29ca288fe225ea

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't show us all the code?

I think you've forgot to declare your main module, but can't verify with code you provided.

Please see above a working code:

```
angular.module('bitbloqApp', []);

angular.module('bitbloqApp').controller('softwareTabCtrl', softwareTabCtrl);

function softwareTabCtrl($scope){
  $scope.txt = 'This is working';
}
```

**Full: https://plnkr.co/edit/dwIfwY6f7Yu3v7wCPVuO**

Comment: The full code is here:

https://gist.github.com/raulvillora/e6ef8fdda865230b3d9a71206c20702a

Comment: Where is your main app module, where you inject your dependencies?